# Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm receiving this error

Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed

My solution was: execute this query

```
exec sp_configure 'user instances enabled', 1.
```

GO
Reconfigure

later, deleted this folder :

```
C:\Documents and Settings\{YOUR_USERNAME}\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\{SQL_INSTANCE_NAME}
```

and restart my computer. !

ok , when I restarted my computer ,I had success ,but every time when I restart the visual studio and my web application , I receive again this error .

What can I do?

Comment: Why do you want to use user instances? This is a deprecated feature and really shouldn't be used.

Comment: i don't want ,but when i run : exec sp_configure 'user instances enabled', 0. i get other error. what is the best way?

Comment: Don't understand why you need to do anything with sp_configure. Change your visual studio project so that the database connection strings don't say anything about user instances (or attachdbfilename).